# How to pass an argument to an as pattern in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
    calcDivisors :: [Int] -> [Int]
    calcDivisors as = filter alldiv [1..7]
        where alldiv b = all ((==) 0 . mod b) as
```

Instead of calling `[1..7]` I want to call a variable list inside that function. I do not understand where to add my list parameter.

Doing it like

```
calcDivisors list as = ...
```

does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function already has an argument `as`. Just use it in your function like

```
    calcDivisors :: [Int] -> [Int]
    calcDivisors as = filter alldiv as
        ...
```

and call it with `calcDivisors [1..7]`.